# How to send data from URL to Post Request Method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm developing an `MVC4` application and using Web API for my web services to send data for android application and i need some testing on the results so when i use GET Request Method  i put in the browser this URL

```
http://localhost:2100/api/Accounts/LogIn?UserName=Fadi&PassWord=123456
```

this is my method

```
[HttpGet]
    public ConfrmationMessage LogIn(string UserName, string PassWord)
    {
        ConfrmationMessage flag = new ConfrmationMessage();

        if (WebSecurity.Login(UserName, PassWord))
        {
            flag.status = "LogedIn";
            return flag;
        }

        else
        {
            flag.status = "The user name or password provided is incorrect.";
            return flag;
        }

    }
```

and every thing work fine but when i'm using an `[HttpPost]` and use this URL again

```
http://localhost:2100/api/Accounts/LogIn?UserName=Fadi&PassWord=123456
```

it give me this error

```
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}
```

so i did do some search and find that the post method use anther way to put data from URL [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)  but still can not understand how to write the correct URL for the post method so any help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you submit a post request via a form element like so (there are more attributes you can add but you can look these up easily.

```
<form action="~/api/Accounts/LogIn" method="POST">
    <!--input elements here -->
</form>
```

or through an ajax call (requires jquery)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "~/api/Accounts/LogIn",
    type: "POST",
    data: { UserName: "Fadi", PassWord: "123456" }
    success: function(result) {
        //do something when response is successful (result is the response)
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //will return exception info from server
        //jqXHR is the request in xml format
        //textStatus is the description of the exception (if there is one)
        //errorThrown is the excception object thrown (if there is one)
    }
});
```